# How to use parameters given from command line in C?

Tags: c, input, arguments

I have to make an exe file that can be run from command line, taking a few parameters as well as an option (unsure what it's actually called, sorry, will describe).

The input to the command line would be along the lines of:

```
filename -x input_file output_file a b c d
```

Where -x is an option as to what the program will do (-e is encrypt, -d is decrypt, etc).

My issue is actually getting all of the parameters into the program and associated with variable names. I've looked for information on the internet, but couldn't find anything that helped me with this format (in C).

Comment: What about the first hit in Google on "command line arguments c": http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson14.html

Comment: You seem to be looking for [getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might help you:
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html

For more information, you might want to search for "getopt" and compare your needs to what PERL GetOpt does.

Answer (score 4):

`getopt` is your friend. It helps you handle command line options.

You can find a full example on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt).